# Reverse JSON query: find all queries in a collection matching an object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I am designing a **generic** notification subscription system where user can specify a compound rule at the time of subscription in terms of MongoDB query, or more generally, json query. The subscription data is stored in MongoDB collection. For example,

```
{ "userId": 1, "rule": {"p1": "a"} }
{ "userId": 2, "rule": {"p1": "a", "p2": "b"} }
{ "userId": 3, "rule": {"p3": {$gt: 3} } }
```

Later when an event in the form of a json object, such as the following, arrives, I want to find all user rules the event maches:

```
{"p1": "a", "p3": 4}
```

The above event should match rules specified by userId 1 and 3 in the example. The event object doesn't have to be stored in MongoDB.

Although I can probably meet the requirement by writing a loop at application layer. For efficiency I really want to implement it at db layer, preferably allow distributed (sharded) execution due to volume and latency requirement.

Is it achievable? Any help is appreciated. In fact, I am open to other NOSQL dbs as long as supporting dynamic event schema and there is a way to specify compound rule.

Comment: How much 'specificity' do you *really* need? Often you can do a query partially in the DB and the rest in the application. For example, would matching documents containing references to "p1" and "p3", bringing just them client-side and then evaluating the rule be sufficient? How many 'variables' are there and how many of each combination of 'variables'?

Comment: Basically I want to avoid writing a loop of users/rules at app level. The notification subscription system is generic such that the schema of event is unknown in advance by me as the author of the system, but known by the developers who apply the system to a specific business app, say a road incident alerting system. The developers are also responsible to compose the rules from user inputs.

Comment: Well you could use `$where` but the function would be huge as for each variable in the input you would need to check that it exists, check if it's an object, look for $lt, $gt, ... do the appropriate comparisons, ... You could code-generate this expression. It won't be fast as it has to examine every document; you could couple it with a pre-filter on the presence of the necessary variables as suggested above. But ... do you *really* have hundreds of thousands of rules with the same parameters that would make it worthwhile to do this database-side or is this just some personal preference?

Answer (score 7):

What you are trying to achieve is not possible, at least in MongoDB.

If you reason about how a query engine works, you will realize that this has not a straightforward solution.

On high-level terms, the engine will generate a condition object from your query that then will get evaluated against each document in the set that will result in a boolean value which determines if the document belongs to the result set or not.
In your case you want to do the other way round, you want to generate a condition object based on the document and then apply it to something (e.g an object) that you give it.

Even if it were possible, the cost of doing this on the DB would be too high as it would require to compile an expression function for each object and execute it and there would be no way to optimize the execution of the query.
It is more reasonable to actually do that outside the database, where you could have the expression functions already created.

Comment: Maybe you are correct. But I don't think it's impossible, at least not theoretically. First, because the queries are known in advance, they can be compiled as part of optimization; second, MongoDB supports MapReduce to avoid writing application level loop. I think what's missing is a <compiled_query>.match() method that MongoDB can implement and expose so that I can call in MapReduce.

Answer (score 2):

You cant store "Comparison Query Operators" in a mongo database, but you can do this:

```
{ "userId": 1, "rule": {"p1": "a"} }
{ "userId": 2, "rule": {"p1": "a", "p2": "b"} }
{ "userId": 3, "rule": {"p3":  {"value": 3, "operator":"gt"} } }
```

You store value AND OPERATOR, in string form, and you can make a query like this:

```
db.test.find({"rule.p3.comparator":"gt", "rule.p3.value":{$lt:4}})
```

Notice, if your **"operator"** is **"gt"**, you must use **$lt** (the opposite comparison operator) in the query

Your complete example is something like this:

```
db.test.find({$or:[{"rule.p3.comparator":"gt", "rule.p3.value":{$lt:4}}, {"rule.p1":"a"}]})
```

This query match userId 1 and 3 like you want

Comment: This requires me as the notification system library developer knowing the event schema in advance, making the system applicable to only specific data model.

Comment: I cant imagine how you could develop any library without "knowing the event schema in advance". I mean: you need to design and document your event schema previous to develop your library or application

Comment: If you consider MongoDB as a library, it's designed without needing to know the data schema in advance. That way it works for all schema.

Comment: I agree with @Sanss:  What you are trying to achieve is not possible (exactly you show us)

Comment: I have replied to his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update: Following solution doesn't work. Problem with mongodb is that it doesn't use NodeJs to run map-reduce javascript, nor support any package manager. So it's hard to use any 3rd party libraries.

My own proposed solution, <s>which hasn't been confirmed</s> :

1. Compose query conforming to [json-query](https://github.com/mmckegg/json-query) syntax
2. upon arrival of `evt`, call MongoDB [mapReduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/) function on user rules collection to invoke `jsonQuery` in mapper

   ```
    var jsonQuery = require('json-query')
    var mapper = function(evt) {
        function map() {
            if(jsonQuery(this.rule, {data: evt}){
                emit(this.userId);
            }
        }
        return map;
    };
    db.userRules.mapReduce(mapper(evt), ...);
   ```

The reason to compose query into json-query syntax instead of MongoDB query syntax is only json-query offers the `jsonQuery` method that tries to match one rule to one object. For above code to meet the requirements in question, following assumptions have to be met:

1. MongoDB can execute `mapReduce` on distributed nodes
2. In `mapReduce` I can use external library such as `json-query`, which implies the library code has to be distributed to all MongoDB nodes, perhaps as a result of closure.

Comment: You might want to look at [mongo-query](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-query)
 and/or [filtr](https://github.com/logicalparadox/filtr/). I'm about to explore them myself. Note that depending on your situation, it may be worth querying mongo for all/recent/user-specific rules, but then doing the rule-testing on your non-mongo server.

Comment: @dan-man, I ended up with what you said - doing rule-testing at app side rather than in mongodb. I used JMESPath as rule eval lib. Problem with mongodb is that it doesn't use NodeJs to run map-reduce javascript, nor any package manager. So I am unable to use any 3rd party libraries. I have also solved app-side horizontal scalability issue to fully meet my objective.